# BTRFS snapshot changes summary

Tags: btrfs

I use `btrfs send -p` with `btrfs receive` to do incremental backups.  Something like this:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /data /data/.snapshots/newSnapshot
btrfs send -p /data/.snapshots/lastSnapshot /data/.snapshots/newSnapshot | btrfs receive /backup/.snapshots
btrfs subvolume delete /data/.snapshots/lastSnapshot
btrfs subvolume delete /backup/.snapshots/lastSnapshot
mv /data/.snapshots/newSnapshot /data/.snapshots/lastSnapshot
mv /backup/.snapshots/newSnapshot /backup/.snapshots/lastSnapshot
```

It works fine but doesn't provide much feedback.

Is there a way to get a summary of how much data is to be transferred?  Can I get any statistics at all about the differences between two snapshots?  I'm mainly interested in the total amount of changed data.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply pipe the send stream through `pv` like this:

```
btrfs send ... | pv | btrfs receive ...
```

It'll show you the transfer speed as well as the already transferred size and of course that size will be visible in the end too.

Comment: Using `btrfs send ... | pv -fbn 2>> logFile.txt | btrfs receive ...` does provide a summary with the number of bytes sent, but it isn't exactly the number of bytes changed.  There is some overhead for `send` to indicate where the data is to be written.  Still, this is close and the solution functional.